# Using RegExp with ng-if

Tags: angularjs

I'd like to use `RegExp` with `ng-if` synthax, but it seems not working as desired.

My code :

```
<td ng-if="item.name.match(new RegExp(/.png|.jpg|.jpeg/, 'gi')).length"><img ng-src="/uploads/{{item.name}}"></td>
<td ng-if="!item.name.match(new RegExp(/.png|.jpg|.jpeg/, 'gi')).length">No image</td>
```

Comment: can you use `ng-pattern`?

Comment: Not, because `ng-pattern` are not offering a conditional expression...

Comment: then it needs to be a function that takes a regex and an item as parameters

Comment: Ok thank you. It works with a function...

Answer (score 1):

I suggest preventing add that logic to the view.

You can create a function, for example `validateAssets(item)` on the `ng-if` where the parameter is evaluated using Regex on the controller.

Keep rocking!